# Dotnetnuke inject script only for particular module

Tags: dotnetnuke

I want a javascript to be executed when a particular module loads only for a particular portal.

On only one portal this script needs to be executed when that module loads,

Is this possible, could you provide any references, i have googled and dint find any links

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really depends on exactly what the module is, but if it is a limited item.  You could just add the needed JS to the "Header" or "Footer" of the module that you can find under "Settings" for the module.

This way, you are handling it as a one-off and it is ONLY done on the instances of the module that you need it to be done on.